# How to create a layout at runtime in android and put json values to them?

Tags: android, json, android-layout

I'm creating an app for my website and using API for sending Json data. I want to know how to create a layout at runtime and put values of JSON Nodes in it. Like for TextView i want to show the date send from JSON.

MY Layout is :

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/question_content"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/questions">
        <!-- Month and Year on the top -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#22C778"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="December 2014"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/month_name"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <!-- Date and Month On The Left -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="30 Jan"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#F1F1F1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/date_text"
            android:layout_below="@+id/month_name"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            />

        <!-- Question Title  -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="This Is The Title Of Question Of January"
            android:id="@+id/question_title"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/date_text"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date_text" />

        <!--  Question Description -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="This Is The Description Of The Question You See Above And Below Is The Rating Bar"
            android:id="@+id/question_desc"
            android:layout_below="@+id/question_title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date_text"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/date_text" />

        <RatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/question_rating"
            android:numStars="1"
            android:stepSize="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/question_desc"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/question_desc"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/question_desc"

            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="0 people rated this question"
            android:id="@+id/people_rated"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/question_rating"
            android:layout_below="@+id/question_desc"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/question_rating" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to generate this linear layout at runtime and put a value to each of its view from Json Nodes.
How to do that.

Comment: You want to create a VIEW(from the above layout) and populte the values into its TextView.. right ?

Comment: No i want to create the above layout dynamically. and the Values in TextView i.e, text ,will be set through json nodes

Comment: what you have tried so far @ManushChand?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to create the above layout programmatic-ally. follow this link 
:http://androidexample.com/Dynamically_Create_View_Elements__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=115&aaid=137